# matlab matrix with non-same dimension

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

i have matrix C01 <0>, matrix C02 <50x1800 double>, matrix C3 <50x34 double> and i need to transform it to one thing C(i), for using expression like this C(1) = C01, C(2) = C02.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) and refer individual elements as `C{1} = C01`, `C{2} = C02`, etc.

You can also create the cell array as `C = {C01, C02, C03};`

Notice that you still can use `C(1)` syntax for cell array, but this statement will return not the original numeric matrix, but the matrix encapsulated into a cell array with one element.

Comment: hmmm.... in the future functions i need to use plot(C(i,x,y),t). how it will works?

Comment: What do `i`,`x` and `y` index? An original matrix or array of matrices? You can actually apply cell array index and matrix index sequencially, for example, `C{i}(x,y)`. It will return element in x-th row and y-th column of i-th matrix.

Comment: thakns a lot! very simple =)